# Plot 2 sets of categorical data on a bar graph with category vs frequency in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a data set that has categorised data over two time periods (x and y). I would like to display the data on a bar graph to look something like the sketch below using the R statistical software.

[image]

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c('Red','Black','Green','Blue'), y=c('Red','Black','Black','Red'))

ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x=x))+ geom_bar(aes(x=y))
```

However, this produces a plot that combines all the data, rather than plotting it separately:

[image]

Can anyone support me in achieving the hand drawn image?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest pivoting it into long, counting the frequency, then plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(x=c('Red','Black','Green','Blue'), y=c('Red','Black','Black','Red'))
# here's the pivot
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(everything())
tab = data.frame(table(df$value,df$name)) 
ggplot(tab,aes(x=Var1,y=Freq,fill=Var2)) + geom_col(position="dodge")
```

Brief explanation, using table on two variables will return you the occurrence of one w.r.t the other. With this data frame, you call ggplot, the slight adjustment is to use geom_col which plots the y stated in aes, and use position="dodge" so they are side by side, instead of stacked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I've tried your suggestion, but the chart produced doesn't look like yours.
`df <- data.frame(x=c('Red','Black','Green','Blue'), y=c('Red','Black','Black','Red'))
tab = data.frame(table(df$x,df$y))
ggplot(tab,aes(x=Var1,y=Freq,fill=Var2)) + geom_col(position="dodge")`

Comment: Arh yes, sorry you see that you have a character for one column and factor for the other? You need to make it factor for both. See my updated answer.

Comment: So like this:
`df <- data.frame(x=c('Red','Black','Green','Blue'), y=c('Red','Black','Black','Red'))
tab = data.frame(table(factor(df$x),factor(df$y)))
ggplot(tab,aes(x=Var1,y=Freq,fill=Var2)) + geom_col(position="dodge")`

Still seems to not produce your graph - maximum  y value stays at 1.00

Comment: For `value` and `name` should I be using x and y?

Comment: sorry can you be more specific about what is different? The data.frame you are using now, is different from what is in your question

Comment: My code currently looks like this.  
`df <- data.frame(x=c('Red','Black','Green','Blue'), y=c('Red','Black','Black','Red'))`  
`tab = data.frame(table(factor(df$value),factor(df$name)))`  
`ggplot(tab,aes(x=Var1,y=Freq,fill=Var2)) + geom_col(position="dodge")`  
And the output gives the error:  
`Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Var1' not found`

Comment: hi @llewmihs, so sorry for the confusion. I forgot to include the pivot long step. It should be correct now